# Keras augmentation does not work with tf.data.Dataset map

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I'm trying to get a preprocessing function to work with the Dataset map, but I get the following error (full stack trace at the bottom):

```
ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.
```

Below is a full snippet that reproduces the issue. My question is, why in one use case (crop only) it works, and when RandomFlip is used it doesn't? How can this be fixed?

```py
import functools
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def data_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        x = np.random.random(size=(80, 80, 3)) * 255  # rgb image
        x = x.astype('uint8')
        y = np.random.random(size=(40, 40, 1)) * 255  # downsized mono image
        y = y.astype('uint8')
        yield x, y


def preprocess(image, label, cropped_image_size, cropped_label_size, skip_augmentations=False):

    x = image
    y = label

    x_size = cropped_image_size
    y_size = cropped_label_size

    if not skip_augmentations:
        x = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal")(x)
        y = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal")(y)

        x = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=1.0, fill_mode='constant')(x)
        y = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=1.0, fill_mode='constant')(y)

    x = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(x_size, x_size)(x)
    y = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(y_size, y_size)(y)

    return x, y


print(tf.__version__) # 2.6.0
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_gen, output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(80, 80, 3), dtype='uint8'),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(40, 40, 1), dtype='uint8')
))

crop_only_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, cropped_image_size=50, cropped_label_size=25, skip_augmentations=True)
train_preprocess_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, cropped_image_size=50, cropped_label_size=25, skip_augmentations=False)

# This works
crop_dataset = dataset.map(crop_only_fn)

# This fails: ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable
train_dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess_fn)
```

Full-stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./issue_dataaug.py", line 50, in <module>
    train_dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess_fn)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1861, in map
    return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4985, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4218, in __init__
    self._function = fn_factory()
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3151, in get_concrete_function
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3116, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3463, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3308, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1007, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4195, in wrapped_fn
    ret = wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4125, in wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(self._func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 695, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    ./issue_dataaug.py:25 preprocess  *
        x = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal")(x)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py:414 __init__  **
        self._rng = make_generator(self.seed)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py:1375 make_generator
        return tf.random.Generator.from_non_deterministic_state()
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/stateful_random_ops.py:396 from_non_deterministic_state
        return cls(state=state, alg=alg)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/stateful_random_ops.py:476 __init__
        trainable=False)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/stateful_random_ops.py:489 _create_variable
        return variables.Variable(*args, **kwargs)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:268 __call__
        return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:262 _variable_v2_call
        shape=shape)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:243 <lambda>
        previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py:2675 default_variable_creator_v2
        shape=shape)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:270 __call__
        return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1613 __init__
        distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
    /...//virtualenvs/cvi36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1695 _init_from_args
        raise ValueError("Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be "

    ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.
```

Comment: With the given code above, could you please ensure reproducibility? The error you mention is expected and but the given code, I didn't get the same error that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the error that you mentioned I didn't find reproducible. However, it simply needs to initialize the augmentation layers within the `__init___` method.

> ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped
> in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file
> a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.

---

Here is the full working code.

```
def data_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        x = np.random.random(size=(80, 80, 3)) * 255  # rgb image
        x = x.astype('uint8')
        y = np.random.random(size=(40, 40, 1)) * 255  # downsized mono image
        y = y.astype('uint8')
        yield x, y


class Augment(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, seed=42):
        super().__init__()
        self.flip_a = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", seed=seed)
        self.flip_b = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", seed=seed)

        self.rot_a = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=1.0,
                                 fill_mode='constant', seed=seed)
        self.rot_b = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=1.0, 
                                fill_mode='constant', seed=seed)
        
    def call(self, inputs, labels):
        x = self.flip_a(inputs)
        x = self.rot_a(x)

        y = self.flip_b(labels)
        y = self.rot_b(y)
        return x, y
```

```
def preprocess(image, label, cropped_image_size, cropped_label_size):
    x = image
    y = label
    x_size = cropped_image_size
    y_size = cropped_label_size

    x = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.float32)

    x = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(x_size, x_size)(x)
    y = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(y_size, y_size)(y)

    x = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.uint8)
    y = tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.uint8)
    return x, y
```

**Data**

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_gen, output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(80, 80, 3), dtype='uint8'),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(40, 40, 1), dtype='uint8')
))
```

**Test 1**

```
crop_only_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, 
                                 cropped_image_size=50,  
                                 cropped_label_size=25)

# This works
crop_dataset = dataset.map(crop_only_fn)
x, y = next(iter(crop_dataset))
x.shape, y.shape
(TensorShape([50, 50, 3]), TensorShape([25, 25, 1]))
```

**Test 2**

```
train_preprocess_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, 
                                        cropped_image_size=50,
                                        cropped_label_size=25)
train_dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess_fn)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(Augment()) # < calling now.
x, y = next(iter(train_dataset))
x.shape, y.shape
(TensorShape([50, 50, 3]), TensorShape([25, 25, 1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure this is directly related to your issue, but on `TF` 2.7 your code is not working at all, because all the `Keras` augmentation layers expect `float` values and not `uint8`. So, maybe try casting your data like this:

```py
import functools
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def data_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        x = np.random.random(size=(80, 80, 3)) * 255  # rgb image
        x = x.astype('uint8')
        y = np.random.random(size=(40, 40, 1)) * 255  # downsized mono image
        y = y.astype('uint8')
        yield x, y


def preprocess(image, label, cropped_image_size, cropped_label_size, skip_augmentations=False):

    x = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(label, dtype=tf.float32)

    x_size = cropped_image_size
    y_size = cropped_label_size

    if not skip_augmentations:
        x = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal")(x)
        y = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal")(y)

        x = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=1.0, fill_mode='constant')(x)
        y = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=1.0, fill_mode='constant')(y)

    x = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(x_size, x_size)(x)
    y = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(y_size, y_size)(y)

    return tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.uint8), tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.uint8)


print(tf.__version__) # 2.6.0
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_gen, output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(80, 80, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(40, 40, 1), dtype=tf.uint8)
))

crop_only_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, cropped_image_size=50, cropped_label_size=25, skip_augmentations=True)
train_preprocess_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, cropped_image_size=50, cropped_label_size=25, skip_augmentations=False)

# This works
crop_dataset = dataset.map(crop_only_fn)

# This fails: ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable
train_dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess_fn)
```

On a side note, the `Keras` augmentation layers are usually used as part of a model that you plan to train. You could alternatively use the `tf.image` functions for example `tf.image.central_crop`, `tf.image.random_flip_left_right` or even `tfa.image.rotate`.

***Update 1:*** You are getting the error mentioned in the comments, because as documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers), the layers `tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip` and `tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation` are only active during training. So try using other methods:

```py
import functools
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

def preprocess(image, label, cropped_image_size, cropped_label_size, skip_augmentations=False):

    x = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(label, dtype=tf.float32)

    x_size = cropped_image_size
    y_size = cropped_label_size

    if not skip_augmentations:
        x = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(x)
        y = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(y)
        
        x = tfa.image.rotate(x, 90, fill_mode='constant')
        y = tfa.image.rotate(y, 90, fill_mode='constant')


    x = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(x_size, x_size)(x)
    y = tf.keras.layers.CenterCrop(y_size, y_size)(y)

    return tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.uint8), tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.uint8)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_gen, output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(80, 80, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(40, 40, 1), dtype=tf.uint8)
))

crop_only_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, cropped_image_size=50, cropped_label_size=25, skip_augmentations=True)
train_preprocess_fn = functools.partial(preprocess, cropped_image_size=50, cropped_label_size=25, skip_augmentations=False)

crop_dataset = dataset.map(crop_only_fn)
train_dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess_fn)

image, _ = next(iter(train_dataset.take(1)))

plt.imshow(image.numpy())
```

I excluded `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation`, since it does not seem to be working with tensors right now.

Comment: I tried with TF 2.7 (after casting the data to be float32) and the mapping statement is executed without exceptions. However, the issue seem to go to another place: creating an iterator to both datasets and taking one example with next() works on the crop_dataset, but not on train_dataset. Something about errors_impl.NotFoundError NOT FOUND {{node random_flip_1/stateful_uniform_full_int/RngReadAndSkip}}.